# SetTimeout() won't execute the function

Tags: vbscript, settimeout, internet-explorer-11

So this is my code snippet:

```
'in VBScript

Sub Main()
   Dim timeoutTimer

   'more scripts here
   'more scripts here
   'more scripts here

   timeoutTimer = window.setTimeout("alert()", 2000)

   Call WaitForAnEvent() 'This function waits for an event to happen
                         'if there is no event then code execution stop's
                         'and wait
   'more scripts here
   'more scripts here
   'more scripts here
End Sub 

Sub alert()
   MsgBox "Help!"
End Sub
```

What happens is, there are times when `alert()` is not triggered, and I don't have any idea why. I conducted some research about setTimeout() and they said that setTimeout will be triggered if the timer expires and as soon as there is an available opportunity to execute it. I believe after `WaitForAnEvent()` is invoked there will be an available opportunity for setTimeout to be executed but 
**sometimes it is** and **sometimes it is not.**

**Update** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I had been reading a lot of articles about `setTimeout` and they all say(in short) that it cannot be triggered if the browser is busy doing something.

Now:

- Is it correct to assume that the browser is doing something(infinite), and
  setTimeout cannot find an available moment to trigger the function?
- Is there a way in VBScript/Javascript to check if IE(browser) is currently doing somthing like rendering text or executing some scripts?

Comment: Why is the tagged Javascript?  It doesn't look like Javascript.

Comment: @jfriend00 You"re right, VBScript is Server-Side code. It has client side versions but only in IE. It's very different from JavaScript

Comment: @jfriend00 - sorry about that, but I think `setTimeout` works the same way in vbscript and javascript so I also tag my question in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think you should change your function name from `alert` to something that does not collide with elements exposed by the browser (there is a `window.alert()` function). Maybe this will work as is (not tested), but it is better to avoid confusion
- The proper syntax to bind the event to the handler is to retrieve a reference to the function (here renamed)

  `window.setTimeout(GetRef("showAlert"), 2000)`
- Probably because I don't have enough information, but I don't see the need for your `WaitForAnEvent()` function. Events happen. You bind the function to execute on event and leave to the browser the work to call the event handler when needed

**edited** Just for a sample (adapted from a previous answer)

In this HTA, there are five events being handled: Start button press, Stop button press, Exit button press, Clock interval and File existence check

The basic idea is NOT to have code running all the time. The browser has the control and when an event happens (button pressed or interval reached) the code to handle the event is called and ends.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ClockwithAlerts</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
    ID="ClockHTA"
    APPLICATIONNAME="ClockHTA"
    MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
    SysMenu="no"
    BORDER="thin"
/>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Const TemporaryFolder = 2

Dim timerID, timerFile

Sub Window_onLoad
    window.resizeTo 600,280
    SetClockTimer True 
    timerFile = window.setInterval(GetRef("CheckFilePresence"), 1500)
End Sub

Sub CheckFilePresence
    Dim myFile
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        myFile = .BuildPath(.GetSpecialFolder( TemporaryFolder ), "test.txt")
        If .FileExists(myFile) Then 
            fileStatus.innerText = "FILE ["& myFile &"] FOUND"
        Else
            fileStatus.innerText = "File ["& myFile &"] is not present"
        End If
    End With
End Sub 

Sub SetClockTimer( Enabled )
    If Enabled Then 
        timerID = window.setInterval(GetRef("RefreshTime"), 1000)
        RefreshTime
    Else 
        window.clearInterval(timerID)
        timerID = Empty 
    End If
    StartButton.disabled = Enabled
    StopButton.disabled = Not Enabled
End Sub

Sub RefreshTime
    CurrentTime.InnerHTML = FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime)
End Sub

Sub ExitProgram
    If Not IsEmpty(timerID) Then window.clearInterval(timerID)
    If Not IsEmpty(timerFile) Then window.clearInterval(timerFile)
    window.close()
End Sub

</SCRIPT>

</head>

<body>
    <input id="checkButton" type="button" value="EXIT" name="run_button" onClick="ExitProgram" align="right">
<br><br>
    <span id="CurrentTime"></span>
<br><br>
    <input id="Stopbutton"  type="button" value="Stop"  name="StopButton"  onclick="SetClockTimer(False)">
    <input id="StartButton" type="button" value="Start" name="StartButton" onclick="SetClockTimer(True)">
    <hr>
    <span id="fileStatus"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answere. I'll try this now. But with regards to the third one I need the `WaitForAnEvent` to be exactly where it is, because all the scripts bellow it is dependent from it. Sorry I was not able to mention this in my question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work in my case. Any other idea?

Comment: @Thorax, if your `WaitForAnEvent` is running, events will not be dispatched. You should bind events to functions and leave to the browser the work to call the event handler. If you need to periodically check for something in `WaitForAnEvent`, use a `setInterval`.

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't really get what you mean, I'm very new to VBScript and HTA. Could you give me an example, you may put it in the answers. thank you so much

Comment: @Thorax, sample HTA is included in answer.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this very awesome sample. You just just teach me a lot of things in your sample. But unfortunately it can't be applied in my current situation. I'll explain why in my next comment

Comment: I've code using C++ but not VBS(sorry). The `WaitForAnEvent()` function will invoke `::GetMessage` which is in a DLL file written in C++ language. This function will wait for a message(Windows events) to be send and if there is no message it will wait untill a message is send then return a value back to the VBScript counterpart. Because of this the code execution stops/pause.

Comment: @Thorax, then you can modify the C++ code, replacing `GetMessage` with `PeekMessage` and return the control to the browser as soon as possible. Then create an interval to call the message check operation.

Comment: Now that's an idea. I'll have to redesign the entire system for this, so it might take some time. I'll mark this correct if it works. Thank you so much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try remove quotes around your function name:

`timeoutTimer = window.setTimeout(alert, 2000)`

Comment: hi, tried your solution but did not work. It gives me and error `Type mismatch 'alert'`

Comment: I think maybe alert is a system function, can you try change your function name to something else?