# Vbscript check hour difference within a loop

Tags: vbscript

I want to check the time difference of 1 hour within a loop. A `Do-loop` will be running and every single time it will see if the difference of current time and previous time period is 1 hour .

I wrote this , but i guess this is way complicated

```
Dim ti_me
Public Function storetime(arg1,arg2)
  da_te = Time
  If (DateDiff("h",da_te,arg1)=1 Or -1) Then
    WScript.Echo DateDiff("h",da_te,arg1)&" hour"
  End If
  ti_me = arg2
End Function

Call storetime("1:18:22 PM",Time)

Do
  a = Time
  Call storetime(a,"")
  WScript.Sleep 2000
Loop
```

Please Correct me .

Comment: Nothing to correct, IMHO looks OK.

Comment: This kind of question is more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is vbscript capable of multitasking ? For instance , running a `do-loop` for one function and `sleep` for another ?

Comment: No, VBScript in general doesn't support multitasking/-threading. There are a few exceptions to that rule, but I don't think they apply to what you described in your question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers what are those exceptions ? Maybe i can relate something and improve .

Comment: Things like [`SetTimeout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30522163/1630171) for instance. But frankly, I fail to see what you need multitasking for in the code you posted. Perhaps you should take a step back and ask about the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of asking questions about what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible . Nothing else

Comment: Like I said: in a very limited form, under very specific circumstances. Not worth wasting time on it IMO.